# Preload HTTPS connection via loading a small image from HTTPS URL

Tags: javascript, http, https, preload

a few days ago while I was checking the source code of a website I came across this little piece of code:

```
//<![CDATA[

Ext.onReady(function() {
    // Preload HTTPS connection via loading a small image from HTTPS URL.
    var HTTPSImage = new Image();
    HTTPSImage.src = 'https://www.example.com/1x1.png';
});

//]]>
```

Can you help me to understand how this "trick" works ?
Thanks in advance.